# Better interpolation for a step-wise function

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have the following data and commands.

```
clc;clear;
t = [0:0.001:0.01];
t_new = [0:0.00001:0.01];
y = [0.9999, 0.9998, 0.9997, 0.9996, 0.9995, 0.0005, 0.0004, 0.0003, 0.0002, 0.0001,0];
p = interp1(t,y,t_new,'spline');
plot(t,y,'o',t_new,p)
```

You can see that y array behaves kind of logistic function with very abrupt drop from near one to to near zero. I need to use an interpolation function. Looks like my option is not a very good match as can be seen especially between the nodes 0.003 and 0.004, for example. Is there a better/"universal|" way to interpolate such functions with abrupt value changes in y values?

Thank you.

Comment: No, there is not a one fit all solution as it depends on what you want/context information. There are an infinite number of ways to interpolate discrete sampled data. In this case linear or pchip (shape-preserving piecewise cubic interpolation) may be better.

Comment: Thank you. This would have been better? clc;clear;
t = [0:0.001:0.01];
t_new = [0:0.00001:0.01];
y = [0.9999, 0.9998, 0.9997, 0.9996, 0.9995, 0.0005, 0.0004, 0.0003, 0.0002, 0.0001,0];
p = interp1(t,y,t_new,'pchip');
plot(t,y,'o',t_new,p)

Comment: In this case, probably yes.